# Can I implement an own decorator for resilience4j to optimize rate limiting?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I want to optimize the *resilience4j* rate limiter to allow

- a rate limiting **per user**
- a **staggered rate limiting** (like 1 call/second but only 30 calls/minute but only 1000 calls/hour).

This should protect a resource from DOS attacks but not limit the "normal" user.

Is it possible to reach this with the default resilience4j decorators or can I write my own decorator?

(Or is my approach completely wrong to counteract a DOS attack in this way?)

Comment: You might also DM [Robert Winkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5077433/robert-winkler)

Answer (score 1):

You might use `.andThen(secondDecorator)` like [a fixed issue](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/357) does mention

```java
protected <T> Function<Publisher<T>, Publisher<T>> decorateWithCircuitBreakerForSpecificEndpoint() {
    final CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
        .failureRateThreshold(100)
        .recordFailure(throwable -> throwable instanceof RuntimeException)
        .ringBufferSizeInClosedState(10)
        .ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState(10)
        .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(5_000))
        .build();
    final CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = this.circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("test1", circuitBreakerConfig);
    return CircuitBreakerOperator.<T>of(circuitBreaker).andThen(decorateWithCircuitBreakerForSpecificHost());
}

protected <T> Function<Publisher<T>, Publisher<T>> decorateWithCircuitBreakerForSpecificHost() {
    final CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
        .failureRateThreshold(10)
        .recordFailure(throwable -> throwable instanceof RuntimeException)
        .ringBufferSizeInClosedState(5)
        .ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState(5)
        .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(5_000))
        .build();
    final CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = this.circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("test2", circuitBreakerConfig);
    return CircuitBreakerOperator.<T>of(circuitBreaker);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `andThen()` - must try it for rate limiting

Comment: @datz keep us in touch, that might be helpful for others

Comment: We decided to protect the system by using a Web Application Firewall (WAF).
Nevertheless, I think that limiting the rate by users in this way is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand why, resilience4j does match your use case.
Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395768/11825162) limiting per apikey (which is the same as limiting per user considering user is logged in and has a unique id)

Comment: just because I didn't know about the LimiterManager!